# How to calculate and return sum and count in 1 sql query based on different condition from same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called Jobs which have a data like below :

```
JobId      JobType      Statistics         JobPostingId
1          Internal     10                 100
2          Internal     20                 100
3          External     30                 100
4          External     40                 100
```

So I am trying to calculate count based on `JobType` as follows:

```
InternalCount = Sum(Statistics)

ExternalCount = Count(*)
```

Query to get top 3 JobPosting for Internal Job Type:

```
  SELECT TOP 3 JobPostingId,SUM(Statistics) InternalCount
    FROM [dbo].[Job]
    WHERE JobType = 'Internal' 
    AND [JobPostingId] in (SELECT * FROM #TempJobPostingId) -- return jobpostingid
    GROUP BY JobPostingId
    ORDER BY Sum(Statistics) DESC
```

Now I want to include result for "External" job posting type as well with all the logic except one condition as below:

```
 SELECT TOP 3 JobPostingId,Count(*) ExternalCount
    FROM [dbo].[Job]
    WHERE JobType = 'External' 
    AND [JobPostingId] in (SELECT * FROM #TempJobPostingId) -- return jobpostingid
    GROUP BY JobPostingId
    ORDER BY Count(*) DESC
```

Final Output:

```
JobPostingId     InternalSum     ExternalCount
100              30                2
```

How to get the above result in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> create table Job (    JobId      int, JobType      varchar(20),[Statistics]         int,JobPostingId int)
> insert into job values(1,'Internal ',10  ,   100);
> insert into job values(2,'Internal ',20   ,  100);
> insert into job values(3,'Internal ',11  ,   100);
> insert into job values(4,'Internal ',21   ,  100);
> insert into job values(5,'External',30     , 100);
> insert into job values(6,'External',40      ,100);
> insert into job values(7,'External',31     , 100);
> insert into job values(8,'External',41      ,100);
> ```

> ```
> create table #TempJobPostingId (jobpostingid int);
> insert into #TempJobPostingId values(100)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> with cte as (
> select jobid, jobtype, [statistics], jobpostingid,row_number()over(partition by jobtype order by [statistics] desc)rn from job where jobtype in('Internal','External')
> )
> select JobPostingId ,  
> sum(case when JobType='Internal' then [Statistics] else 0 end)InternalSum,
> sum(case when JobType='External' then 1 else 0 end)ExternalCount
> from cte where rn<=3 and [JobPostingId] IN (SELECT * FROM #TempJobPostingId)
> group by JobPostingId
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> JobPostingId | InternalSum | ExternalCount
> -----------: | ----------: | ------------:
>          100 |          52 |             3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=649e100f551a715b052f62c50eae44a8)*

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem? Or you are still facing any difficulties?

Comment: Yes,it does. Sorry for the late reply. I missed your comment. I have a question that what is the difference between  "sum(case when JobType='External' then 1 else 0 end)ExternalCount" vs "sum(case when JobType='External' then 1 else 0 end)ExternalCount" ? Which one is better when counting statistics?

Comment: You mentioned same condition twice. Please let me know your question. Will try to help.

Comment: Sum(case when JobType='External' then 1 else 0 end)ExternalCount" vs "Count(case when JobType='External' then 1 else 0 end)ExternalCount"?

Comment: Those are not same condition you can apply both in your query and you will find than second condition count() will return 6 instead of 3 since 0 will also be counted.

Comment: So does that mean Sum is more efficient for this situation ?

Comment: Actually second option will give you wrong answer. with count correct approach is count(case when JobType='External' then 1 else null end)ExternalCount. Instead of 0 you need to mention null in else or don's use else just count(case when JobType='External' then 1 end)ExternalCount.

Comment: I would recommend using the condition with sum().

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks @ILoveStackoverflow. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . Are you lookging for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT TOP 3 JobPostingId,
             SUM(CASE WHEN JobType = 'Internal' THEN Statistics END) as InternalCount,
             SUM(CASE WHEN JobType = 'External' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ExternalCount,
FROM [dbo].[Job] j
WHERE [JobPostingId] IN (SELECT * FROM #TempJobPostingId) -- return jobpostingid
GROUP BY JobPostingId
ORDER BY Sum(Statistics) DESC
```

Comment: If I include the filter of WHERE JobType = 'Internal' or JobType= 'External' then will it be better performance-wise as it won't include unnecessary data?. I have millions of row in this table that's why

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow . . . Presumably yes.  Based on the question, I figured those were the only two values.

Comment: Actually, I have different JobTypes else well but right now, I wanted data only for Internal and External Job types. Now does it make sense to filter data for Internal and External in the where clause or it doesn't affect the query?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow . . . Depending on the relative amounts of data, it could have a big impact -- or little impact.  If there isn't much impact, I probably wouldn't repeat the filters.  Then I could add in other job types without having to adjust the filtering each time.